# Formation of dictionary from list element

Tags: python, list, dictionary, split

Hi I have list as follows which contain meta data from images as follows:

```
['Component 1: Y component: Quantization table 0, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert', 
 'Component 2: Cb component: Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert', 
 'Component 3: Cr component: Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert', 
 'Compression Type: Progressive, Huffman', 'Content-Length: 14312', 'Content-Type: image/jpeg’]
```

I want to make a dictionary using splitting the list “:” in he following format:

```
{Component 1: {Y component: [Quantization table 0, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert’], 
 Component 2: {Cb component: [Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert]}, 
 Component 3: {Cr component: [Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert]}, 
 Compression Type: [Progressive, Huffman],Content-Length: 14312,Content-Type: image/jpeg}
```

Currently I have wrote some code which is not working.

```
def make_dict(seq):
res = {}
if seq[0] is not '':
    for elt in seq:
        k, v = elt.split(':')
        try:
            res[k].append(v)  
        except KeyError:
            res[k] = [v]

print res
```

This code does not work. I have tried other approaches too, but I am not able to get the format.

Comment: Are you expecting a list of dictionary of dictionary as output (as in your first case) ?

Comment: @akira, Please accept sufficient answers with the checkmark button.  It's worth +2 rep to you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension within a dict comprehension using `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
>>> li=['Component 1: Y component: Quantization table 0, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert', 'Component 2: Cb component: Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert', 'Component 3: Cr component: Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert', 'Compression Type: Progressive, Huffman', 'Content-Length: 14312', 'Content-Type: image/jpeg']
>>> d=OrderedDict((sub[0],{sub[1]:sub[2:]}) if sub[2:] else (sub[0],sub[1]) for sub in [item.split(':') for item in li])
>>> d
OrderedDict([('Component 1', {' Y component': [' Quantization table 0, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert']}), ('Component 2', {' Cb component': [' Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert']}), ('Component 3', {' Cr component': [' Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert']}), ('Compression Type', ' Progressive, Huffman'), ('Content-Length', ' 14312'), ('Content-Type', ' image/jpeg')])
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
l = ['Component 1: Y component: Quantization table 0, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert',
     'Component 2: Cb component: Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert',
     'Component 3: Cr component: Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert',
     'Compression Type: Progressive, Huffman', 'Content-Length: 14312', 'Content-Type: image/jpeg']

d = {}

for ele in l:
    spl = ele.split(":", 2)
    if len(spl) == 3:
        k1, k2, v = spl
        d[k1] = {k2: v.split(",")}
    else:
        k,v = spl
        d[k] =   v.split() if "," in v  else v
```

Output:

```
{'Component 1': {' Y component': [' Quantization table 0',
                                  ' Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert']},
 'Component 2': {' Cb component': [' Quantization table 1',
                                   ' Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert']},
 'Component 3': {' Cr component': [' Quantization table 1',
                                   ' Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert']},
 'Compression Type': [' Progressive', ' Huffman'],
 'Content-Length': ' 14312',
 'Content-Type': ' image/jpeg'}
```

To remove the whitespace you can `str.strip` it off:

```
d = {}

for ele in l:
    spl = ele.split(":", 2)
    if len(spl) == 3:
        k1, k2, v = spl
        d[k1] = {k2.strip(): list(map(str.strip,v.split(",")))}
    else:
        k,v = spl
        d[k] = list(map(str.strip, v.split())) if "," in v  else v.strip
```

Output:

```
{'Component 1': {'Y component': ['Quantization table 0',
                                 'Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert']},
 'Component 2': {'Cb component': ['Quantization table 1',
                                  'Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert']},
 'Component 3': {'Cr component': ['Quantization table 1',
                                  'Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert']},
 'Compression Type': ['Progressive', 'Huffman'],
 'Content-Length': '14312',
 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'}
```

Both of which actually match your expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive algorithm like the one below, if you want to handle any level of nesting of dictionaries. Example -

```
def makedict(elem):
    if ':' in elem:
        k,v = map(str.strip, elem.split(':',1))
        return {k:makedict(v)}
    elif ',' in elem:
        elems = list(map(str.strip, elem.split(','))) #Simply map(...) for Python 2.x
        return elems
    return elem
```

If you want to make a dictionary of dictionaries, you can do -

```
d = {}
for elem in s:
    d.update(makedict(elem))
```

Or if you want a list of dictionary of dictionries call the above function for each element in your list in a list comprehension, example -

```
result = [makedict(elem) for elem in yourlist]
```

Demo for dictionary of dictionaries -

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for elem in s:
...     d.update(makedict(elem))
...
>>> d
{'Component 2': {'Cb component': ['Quantization table 1', 'Sampling fac
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(d)
{'Component 1': {'Y component': ['Quantization table 0',
                                 'Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert']},
 'Component 2': {'Cb component': ['Quantization table 1',
                                  'Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert']},
 'Component 3': {'Cr component': ['Quantization table 1',
                                  'Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert']},
 'Compression Type': ['Progressive', 'Huffman'],
 'Content-Length': '14312',
 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'}
```

Comment: Recursion to handle any level of nesting of dictionaries

Comment: I am guessing `{Component 1 : { Y component :` would mean a dict of dict.

Comment: Of course, I did it would be very simply to change the logic from list comp to creating a dictionary of dictionary of dictionaries, as updated in the above example

Answer (score 1):

You can elegantly solve the issue using a recursion, and a split limit (the second argument of `split` can be used to limit the split count):

```
def make_dict(l):
    d = dict()
    for elem in l:
        key, value = elem.split(':', 1)
        if ':' in value:
            d[key] = make_dict([value])
        else:
            d[key] = value
    return d
```

and the test seems to match your expectations:

```
>>> l = ['Component 1: Y component: Quantization table 0, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert',
     'Component 2: Cb component: Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert',
     'Component 3: Cr component: Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert',
     'Compression Type: Progressive, Huffman', 'Content-Length: 14312', 'Content-Type: image/jpeg']
>>> make_dict(l)
{'Component 1': {' Y component': ' Quantization table 0, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert'},
 'Component 2': {' Cb component': ' Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert'},
 'Component 3': {' Cr component': ' Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert'},
 'Compression Type': ' Progressive, Huffman',
 'Content-Length': ' 14312',
 'Content-Type': ' image/jpeg'}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.Its really helpful